# WooCommerce Coupons: Exclude Specific Customer Type

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the WooCommerce Coupons add-on but I'd like to exclude a specific customer type from being able to use the discount. For example, some of my products have specific roles under Dynamic Pricing for Wholesalers. How can I exclude these customer from using the coupons?

For reference, here's the Coupon add-on: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/coupon-management/

Answer (score 1):

I think I've come up with a solution that works by hiding the Coupon input field if the user is a specific type:

```
<?php
   $user = wp_get_current_user();
   if ( ! in_array( 'wholesaler', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
?>

COUPON INPUT FIELD HERE

<?php } ?>
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This will fail if the user applies a coupon when they are logged out, then logs in to the wholesale account. The coupon will still be applied.